# How to restrict environment variables passed to linked containers

Tags: docker

We've started to use docker extensively (and we love it), but have discovered a rather nasty security issue. Linked containers have full access to the source container's environment settings.

For example, say you create a mysql container.

```
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mysql
```

And now you create a wordpress container

```
docker run --name wp --link db:db \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wp \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=1234 \
    -d wordpress
```

If you now inspect the environment in the wordpress container, you'll be able to see the mysql root password.

```
docker exec -i wp sh -c "env|grep ^MYSQL_MYSQL_ENV"

MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.5-m15
```

This is a major security hole !  Any random code or module within the wordpress container could use the mysql root password to connect and reek havoc.  And if the mysql database is shared with multiple wordpress containers (and joomla containers), the havoc could be global.

My question is, is there a way to limit what environment variables are passed between linked containers?

A secondary question -- I've scrutinized the docs on linking containers https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#environment-variables

But it does NOT describe this behavior. I was thinking maybe this was an unintended side effect, and perhaps I should open a bug report?

Comment: "perhaps I should open a bug report?" — That would be my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to limit what environment variables are passed between linked containers?

If this is a concern in your environment, your best bet may be to adopt a solution other than container linking for service discovery.  For example, you could use one of the various `etcd`-backed discovery mechanisms that are out there -- either using `etcd` directly, or something like [consul](https://www.consul.io/), [registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) or [skydns](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns).

Comment: It hadn't even occurred to me to consider another mechanism for service discovery. This is an excellent suggest -- thanks.